# Unit test and Web test on the .NET Framework?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, csla

I would like to know what a Unit test and Web Test is in the .NET Framework and What are the difference between these tests? and How does it affect with the implementation of the CSLA.NET? Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're referring to using MSTest under Visual Studio where they have two modes - testing of code or testing of web site via http calls.

When developing in .NET a developer can choose from several Unit Testing Frameworks such as MSTest - NUnit, MBUnit, XUnit etc. for more information have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127687/favorite-net-unit-testing-framework).

The term Unit Testing refer to a broader field - you can read about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing).

Unit testing refers to the programmer writing simple small tests to verify his code actually work and as such does not effect the implementation of CLSA.NET.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know what a Unit test
>   and Web Test is in the .NET

Do you mean, what unit tesing frameworks are there for .NET ? I recommend you NUnit

Comment: It would be useful to say *why* you recommend it.  Especially since the questioner appears to be using mstest.